Salesforce - Calling multiple actionFunction from Visualforce component and passing value to toast
Please help me here.
Here is my code for reference, since the actionFunction returns only Pagereference or Void, how can I return the value of function to the next function.
<apex:component controller="EXP_DeleteRowActionController" allowDML="true">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!doCheckBeforeDelete}" name="doCheckBeforeDelete" />  
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!deleteRecord}" name="deleteRecord" />
    </apex:form>

    <script>
function handleConfirm() {
            try{
                //I need some logic like this
                //If doCheckBeforeDelete() return true then execute deleteRecord()
                //Here my problem is actionFunction returns only PageReference or Void
                deleteRecord();
            }catch(error){
                myToast();
            }
            
        }
        function myToast(){
            sforce.one.showToast({
                    'title':'zonex',
                    'message':'test',
                    'type':'warning'
                });
        }
    </script>
    </apex:component>

Thanks,
James
